# Cumulative sum of Object type of values in Java

Tags: java, object, cumulative-sum

```
Suppose my value are in object type of array [1,2,3].

for(Object abc : entry.getValue()) {
.
.
Object[] obj = (Object[]) abc ; (values are in abc)

Now I want cumulative sum of obj[1], which I will put in another jsonObject.
```

I know the logic for cumulative sum but due to object type of values it is not working.
Any suggestion on doing cumulative sum of object type of values?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to cast the Object[] to another type, like int[]. Or maybe just the inside like `int i = (int) abc[1]`.
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Would like to know if you tried a few solutions already and what are those?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please find the answer I have posted. It is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reply. Initially I was using

```
int getObjectVal = (int)obj[1])];
```

but it was giving an error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

but it's working, I tried below code

```
int getObjectVal = ((BigInteger) obj[1]).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are speaking about JSON, from JSON you can use

```
arrayAbc=yourJSON.toJsonObject().getJsonArray("nameOfYourArrayField");
```

and then you will have the JSONarray of values.
Once having this you can use `arrayAbc.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()`